# Query to identify if current SQL Server version supports columnstore indexes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, feature-detection, columnstore

I have a stored procedure that creates some dynamic tables. If columnstore indexes are supported on the host version of SQL Server then I want to create a columnstore index, otherwise fallback to creating just a normal row store index.

I have found the `dm_db_persisted_sku_features` table but that just tells you what non-standard features are currently being used rather than what is supported:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features
```

**How can I determine from inside a query if the SQL Server version and edition support columnstore indexes?**

Comment: Why not check the *edition*? Only Enterprise editions support columnstores before SQL Server 2016 SP1

Comment: I could but then I have to navigate the vagaries of SQL Server versions / service packs. Plus it isn't a very future proof solution.

Comment: Actually, it is. Before 2016 SP1, only Enterprise and Developer editions supported columnstores. You can check that with `select SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')`. 2016 SP1 added support for everything.

Comment: there is no fool proof solution,you will have to check edition of SQL server,compatibility level of database as well

Comment: @TheGameiswar server properties arent' affected by compatibility levels

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos:i meant to say,op should check compatibility level of database even though he is on suported edition/version,if he wants to check before creating column store indexes

Comment: @MarkRobinson check [What to tell what SQL Server Version you are running](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1140/how-to-tell-what-sql-server-version-you-are-running/). The `Edition` and `Product Level' properties don't requrie parsing. ProductVersion requires minimal parsing.

Comment: @MarkRobinson in any case, what you ask is not a *product feature*. Perhaps, you should check for the existence of columnstore specific views, eg `SELECT * from sys.system_objects where name='column_store_dictionaries'`

Comment: @TheGameiswar you are right, if someone set a database to the 2008 R2  columnstores wouldn't work either.

Comment: @TheGameiswar SQL Server will create a columnstore index even in compatibility level 10, but process it in [Row Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the compatibility level of the current database to see if it is compatible with 2012+ features.

```
select 
  ColumnStore = case 
    when compatibility_level >= 110 
        and (serverproperty ('edition') like 'Enterprise%'
          or serverproperty ('edition') like 'Developer%')
      then 1 
    when compatibility_level >= 130 
      and serverproperty ('productlevel') != 'RTM'
      then 1 
    else 0 
    end
  from sys.databases 
  where name = db_name()
```

note:

```
SELECT * from sys.system_objects where name='column_store_dictionaries'
```

exists on editions that do not support columnstore indexes (e.g. 2014 Express)

Comment: The compatibility level won't help. Even with compatibility level 10, SQL Server 2014+ will [allow columnstore indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx). They'll be processed in row mode though

Comment: If OP wants to know if he __should__ create columnstore indexes on a database, wouldn't this return the best course of action?